# display div on onload with tha background blur

Tags: javascript, html

I am developing a project where I need to have the user enter the user id and password before entering the other information.

For that I use a `<span>` tag for login and disable the background fields (I paste the background contents in a `<div>`). But I am able to enter the value in the background field. And also when I restore the window, the `<span>` tag will go down. But I need to display it in the center even when I restore the window.

Please guide me to do this.

Comment: Please post the relevant code.

Comment: Are you using any javascript framework in your project? These kind work works will be much simple if you are using some javascript frameworks like jquery, extjs or yui

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery for a modal dialog box

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#example").dialog();
    });


<div id="example" class="flora" title="This is my title">
        Your html
</div>
```

A jQuery modal dialog plugin

[jquery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal)

[jQmodal](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqModal)

Answer (score 0):

This [JQuery Core-UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form) form I have used allot.  It is a really nice way of doing a dialog.